# In what sense 'have' is used in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, modal-verbs

> The courts have made it clear that public interest litigation is in the nature of non-adversarial litigation. This implies that governments and their counsel **have** a different approach to PILs, independent of the governments that they represent.

What is the meaning of the 'have' in the second sentence? Is it used in the sense of 'must have' or 'should have'? Or is it expressing the general meaning of 'have' which is 'to possess'?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you think it just means "have" in the normal sense?

Comment: @gotube After reading the first sentence, it seems that the courts are sort of advising or asking the governments and their counsels to have a different approach toward PILs.  Just using 'have' perhaps means that the governments already have a different approach which is not the case. Am I interpreting it in the wrong way?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're asking. I can't really answer though since I'm having trouble understanding the first sentence. I don't know what "public interest litigation" is, nor how some type of litigation can be "in the nature of non-adversarial litigation".

Comment: @gotube Here's a brief introduction: PIL means litigation filed in a court of law, for the protection of “Public Interest”, such as Pollution, Terrorism, Road safety, Constructional hazards etc. Any matter where the interest of public at large is affected can be redressed by filing a Public Interest Litigation in a court of law. 
  It can be filed against against a State/ Central Govt., Municipal Authorities, and not any private party.

Comment: Non-adversarial means that the procedure should not be seen as a confrontation between the entities and not a trial.                      
   So I guess the courts are asking the state or Union government in this case to not take PIL as a case against them, instead think PILs as working together co-operatively to reach the best resolution for everyone.  There are other points in non adversarial litigations and this definition can't be considered as an accurate one, but I guess it should be enough to understand the background of the sentence which I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and details. I still cannot tell from the context whether "have" in the second sentence is meant to be merely descriptive of government approach in PILs, or if it's meant to instruct government how to approach PILs. What is the document this came from? What's the purpose of the document? Does it introduce people to how PILs happen, or does it declare how they must happen?

Comment: @gotube So It was from an article in a newspaper. The purpose of the article was the renaming of the PILs by the CJI(Chief Justice of India). I think it would be better If I include the picture of the article. But the problem is I have underlined many sentences and circled few words the use of which I find interesting with a blue pen so you may find it hard to read. And also the photo would be blurry. But the part which is in question in the second column a paragraph which is marked with parentheses sign.

Comment: Thanks for all that detail. Unfortunately, to me, it's still ambiguous. She could have meant it either way. I honestly cannot tell whether she meant it as indicating the way it ought to be or the way it is.

Comment: @gotube Thanks gotube for investing your time in this question as I asked this question almost a week ago.  The possibility of have meaning ' should have' troubles me the most. As I searched in many dictionaries and I couldn't find any such uses of have. If the sentence was written in Imperative or subjunctive mood(The courts advised that Government have a different...) I could understand that the subject have any kind of responsibility or duty. But in normal indicative mood...I can't think how it can be used to mean 'should have' or 'ought to have'.

Comment: I hope you can give me some pointers on the grammatical aspect.

Answer (score 1):

> The courts have made it clear that public interest litigation is in the nature of non-adversarial litigation. This implies that governments and their counsel **have** a different approach to PILs, independent of the governments that they represent.

In the second sentence the word **have** means **possess** or **own**. It doesn't mean **must have** or **should have**.

The following example is from Cambridge Dictionary at the word **have** [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have):

> We have a dog.

Here the word **have** has exactly the same meaning with the word **have** of your text. **Have** means **possess** or **own**.

Comment: So does it mean the governments and counsels already possess the different approach in general and they are not being asked by the courts to have?

Comment: @RADS Courts will not ask governments and their counsel about their approach to PILs. Governments and their counsel have the right to have any approach to PILs they want. The meaning is:'The governments and their counsel own a different approach to PILs, independent of the governments that they represent.'Governments that they represent can have the same approach to PILs or have different approach to PILs (than the approach to PILs of their representatives).